# What does _ parameter in Kotlin Lambda

Tags: kotlin

What does the following _ mean in a Kotlin lamda?

```
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
            _: DatePicker, year: Int, month: Int, day: Int ->

        val resultDate : Date = GregorianCalendar(year, month, day).time

        targetFragment?.let { fragment ->
            (fragment as Callbacks).onDateSelected(resultDate)
        }
}
```

I am guessing it means a nameless lambda  parameter which will be unused, but I am not sure and cannot find it using Google.

Comment: just to ignore a param, style thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right that it is for unused parametres. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#underscore-for-unused-variables-since-11